# Refreshing or creating app services button gives error

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-web-app-service

I used to deploy my service from Visual Studio Code, and now suddenly I'm getting errors saying `command 'appService.Refresh' not found`, `command 'appService.CreateWebApp' not found`, etc.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Update VSC to the latest version and then restart.